# Setting matching number of ticks using two axis

Tags: plot, gnuplot, yaxis

I'd like to know how to set the same number of `ytics` for both independent `y` and `y2` axis using *gnuplot*, still using automatic scaling, so that the grid is well aligned.

Right now, as you can see below, there are `6` ticks for the `y` axis and `7` for `y2`, and the chart looks poorly readable.

[image: y2 misalignment]

Comment: Not a full answer, but you can at least remove the y tics from the y2 axis: `set ytics nomirror`. This does not remove the issue with the misaligned grid. There are other solutions, but they involve knowing and specifying beforehand what are the y and y2 ranges. Can you live with that?

Comment: I'm using *gnuplot* for live rough plotting / health monitoring of my system. I guess I'll back up to *Matplotlib* for any more refined data analysis. More precisely, no, I have no clue about my input ranges at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Gnuplot lets you only to specify the increment defining the tics not their count. A slightly dirty workaround would be to first generate the plot into a "fake" terminal, remember the detected autoscaled ranges on each axis, calculate the required tics spacing, and finally generate the image with these settings.

```
N = 6

set term unknown

set ytics
set y2tics #setting y2tics affects autoscale
set ylabel 'MSE'
set y2label 'CE'
set grid

set format y "%.2f"
set format y2 "%.1f"

plot \
    'mse.dat' u 1:2 axis x1y1 w l t 'MSE', \
    'ce.dat' u 1:2 axis x1y2 w l t 'CE'

min_y1 = GPVAL_Y_MIN
max_y1 = GPVAL_Y_MAX

min_y2 = GPVAL_Y2_MIN
max_y2 = GPVAL_Y2_MAX

dy1 = (max_y1 - min_y1) / N
dy2 = (max_y2 - min_y2) / N

set ytics min_y1, dy1
set y2tics min_y2, dy2

set yr [min_y1:max_y1]
set y2r [min_y2:max_y2]

set term png enhanced
set output "test.png"

replot
```

This then produces (using a digitized approximation of your data):
[image]

Comment: I accept this answer just on the base of the accuracy in reproduction of my code-less chart. Moreover it correctly addresses my question. Nevertheless, I'm of the opinion that if I need to use more than 2, 3 lines with *gnuplot*, I'm better off with *Matplotlib*, where I can do proper data analysis, rely on lengthy documentation and exploit *Numpy* and the Python ecosystem. I use to think at *gnuplot* as a graphical `awk`, an everyday tool for one-liners.

Comment: It may also be possible to use stats to avoid the fake plotting.